# How to receive Socket.IO server kill event in iOS client?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I have the following class that manages socket connections with a simple node.js based socket server. For now, I'm only running the socket server locally on port 3000 using `nodemon index.js` in terminal and everything works fine. The only issue I'm facing is that if I quit or close the terminal, I do not receive any event in the client of the server getting killed. Is there any way I can update the client code to check for this? Is it even possible? I'm using Socket.IO v4.7.2 with express v4.18.2 for the server and [v16.1](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/releases) in the iOS client.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import SocketIO

final class SocketService: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var socketManager: SocketManager?
    private var socket: SocketIOClient?
    private let socketURL = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!
    private var namespace: String?
    private let loggingEnabled: Bool = false
    @Published private var socketState = SocketState.disconnected
    
    init() {
        self.socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: socketURL, config: [.log(loggingEnabled), .compress])
        self.socket = socketManager?.defaultSocket
        self.cancellable = $socketState.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { socketState in
            print("socket event: \(socketState)")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        cancellable?.cancel()
        cancellable = nil
        socketManager = nil
        socket = nil
    }
}

// MARK: Socket event listeners
extension SocketService {
    
    private func addEventListeners() {
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.userConnected) { [weak self] data, _ in
            guard let data = data.first as? String else { return }
            self?.namespace = data
            self?.socketState = .userConnected
        }
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.userJoined) { [weak self] data, _ in
            self?.socketState = .userJoined
        }
                
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.userDisconnected) { [weak self] data, _ in
            self?.socketState = .userDisconnected
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Socket user actions
extension SocketService {
    
    private func establishConnection() {
        socketState = .connectingToServer
        addEventListeners()
        socket?.connect()
    }
    
    private func closeConnection() {
        socketState = .disconnected
        guard let namespace = namespace else {
            socket?.disconnect()
            return
        }
        socket?.emit(SocketEvents.disconnectNamespace, namespace)
        socket?.disconnect()
    }
}
```